# CMD has wrong encoding when launched from the Run dialog

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, locale, shift-jis

Some time ago I had to change my system locale from Czech (default) to Japanese because I needed to run some Japanese programs that would otherwise crash.

The problem is, after switching back to Czech, my command prompt would launch with the Shift-JIS encoding whenever I opened it from the Win+R dialog (which is my preferred way of launching cmd). It would also draw characters in a strange bloated font. The problem persists even after uninstalling Japanese from my system altogether.

If I open cmd any other way (Start menu, Right-click Start -> Command Prompt, cmd.exe...), everything works correctly. All settings that I could think of are set to Czech:

- System locale
- Language for non-Unicode programs
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage` (OEMCP value)

Another thing is that Regedit always opens on `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Codepage`, though I don't know if that's related to the problem.

I'm running Windows 10, after the free upgrade from 8.1 and 7. Picture shows the different cmd windows.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMeOi.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings are stored a number of places. Look here for a `codepage` value and delete it.

```
HKCU\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe\
```